# Pass variable as parameter in jQuery

Tags: jquery, bind

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="test" />

<span>0</span>
```

jQuery

```
var input = $('input#test');

input.bind('keyup', function() {
    doThis();
});

input.on('input', function() {
    doThis();
});

function doThis() {
    var wordCounts = {};
    var matches = this.value.match(/\b/g);
    wordCounts[this.id] = matches ? matches.length / 2 : 0;
    var finalCount = 0;
    $.each(wordCounts, function(k, v) {
        finalCount += v;
    });
    $('span#word-count').text(finalCount);
}
```

jsFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/YJVPZ/265/**

Right now `doThis()` doesn't even work. If I was to wrap the contents of `doThis()` with `input.bind('keyup', function() { ... }` it will work just fine. I know it is because it's using an undefined `this`. How can I pass the variable `input` as a parameter?

Is there any way to use .bind and .on together to call for the same function instead of two separate instances as I have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input.bind('keyup input', doThis);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YJVPZ/266/)

By passing a function to `.bind`/`.on` jQuery automatically sets the `this` reference inside of the handler to the element that triggered said event handler (in this case, `#test`).

---

To set the `this` reference manually, which is unnecessary in this case, you'd use [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) / [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
input.bind('keyup input', function() {
    //in this scope, `this` points to `#test`
    doThis.apply(this, arguments); //sets `this` inside of this `doThis` call to
                                   //the same `this` of the current scope.
});
```

We apply `arguments` so that `doThis` also receives the [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) which is passed to event handlers. Not necessary in this specific use case, but it is useful when proxying an event handler that needs to access the arguments passed to the original handler.

---

Side-note: For your code to work, you should move it to the end of the `body` or wrap your code inside of a [DOM ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), that is, put it inside of `$(function(){/*code here*/});`

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
input.on('input keyup', doThis);
```